# Arrange value in JOLT

Tags: json, mapping, transformation, jolt

I want "**externalId**" field before "**status**" field in JOLT.

Any idea why I am getting status before externalId? Also, how do I correct it?

I want Externalid first and then status in the output

/avoid this text please

Stack overflow is saying to many code

below

/

**Input**

```
{
  "PURCHASE_ORDER_DISPATCH": {
    "MsgData": {
      "Transaction": {
        "PO_POD_HDR_EVW1": {
          "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
          "PO_ID": 25052,
          "PO_POD_LN_EVW1": {
            "WG_REQ_ID": 25694,
            "PO_POD_SHP_EVW1": {
              "FREIGHT_TERMS": "FOBDEST",
              "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**JOLT Spec**-

```
[
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
            "#UPSERT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.action",
            "*": {
                "*": {
                    "*": {
                        "*": {
                            "PO_ID": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.externalId",
                            "#APPROVED": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.status",
                            "*": {
                                "WG_REQ_ID": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.poDescription",
                                "*": {
                                    "FREIGHT_TERMS": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTermCode"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**Expected Output-**

```
{
  "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails": {
    "integrationEntities": {
      "integrationEntity": {
        "integrationEntityHeader": {
          "action": "UPSERT"
        },
        "integrationEntityDetails": {
          "poDetails": {
             "externalId": 25052,
            "status": "APPROVED",
      
            "poHeader": {
              "poDescription": 25694,
              "deliveryTermCode": "FOBDEST"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

New Input

[image]

Comment: Hi Sam. That's Spec or input, seems they're confused. Btw, can you please share the input as text rather than an image.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, I have added the output now.

Comment: I think this output is input for the currently shared spec, isn't it? Therefore, you get `"status" : [ "APPROVED", "APPROVED" ]`, but want to see `"status" :  "APPROVED"` ??

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, no that's output that I am getting. I am getting ["APPROVED",["APPROVED", "APPROVED"] in array multiple times. I just want it once like "status" :  "APPROVED".

Comment: well, from what input are you getting that output then ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan      {
  "PURCHASE_ORDER_DISPATCH": {
    "MsgData": {
      "Transaction": {
        "PO_POD_HDR_EVW1": {
          "VENDOR_SETID": "WCOS",
          "PO_ID": 25052,
          "PO_POD_LN_EVW1": {
            "WG_REQ_ID": 25694,
            "PO_POD_SHP_EVW1": {
              "FREIGHT_TERMS": "FOBDEST",
              "BUSINESS_UNIT": "OFIC"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: But, the current **JOLT Input Spec** already **exactly** gives the expected result.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan can you please refresh the question page once. I just messed up with the question. Having little bit of fever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the exact thing you want according to your desired output:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "#UPSERT": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityHeader.action",
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "PO_ID": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.externalId",
              "#APPROVED": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.status",
              "*": {
                "WG_REQ_ID": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.poDescription",
                "*": {
                  "FREIGHT_TERMS": "integration-inbound:IntegrationDetails.integrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.poDetails.poHeader.deliveryTermCode"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "integrationEntityHeader": "&3.&2.&1.&",
            "integrationEntityDetails": {
              "*": {
                "externalId": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "status": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&",
                "poHeader": "&5.&4.&3.&2.&1.&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Note:** If you want to sort based on what exactly you want you need to know that you shouldn't use `*` for selecting keys. instead of that, you should use the name of the key to getting it. like the top spec you can see I wrote `externalId`, `status`, and `poHeader` continuously.

But I did not understand why you need to sort `externalId` and `status` in your JSON output.

[image]

**Update:** If you have an array in your output, You can add the below spec to the end for preventing an array of the same values.

```json
,
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "status": "ONE"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks now external id is coming first. But, there "STATUS: APPROVED" is still coming in array multiple times. I just want it once and not in array. Like- "STATUS':"APPROVED".

Comment: @Sam it is not an array. you can check in on the jolt demo site. I add an image of the output.

Comment: So my input, fields increased that's why I am seeing more "APPROVED" in the fields. Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: I have added new input ss above

Comment: I think you have an array in your input. please check the input exactly. I add a new spec object in my answer for preventing an array of values.

Comment: @Sam use the new spec I added. your issue will be fixed

Comment: Any workaround aside from cardinality spec. Because now I am getting array of some other field.

Comment: @Sam No problem. please replace this line `"status": "ONE"` whit `"*": "ONE"`, if your problem can seen yet, please add a new question with your exact input (Please do not summarize the input).